# bib2gls exception NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, bib2gls

```
$ bib2gls file
bib2gls version 1.5 (2018-05-09)
Reading file.aux
Reading greek-symbols.bib
Encoding: UTF-8
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Vector.sort(Ljava/util/Comparator;)V
    at com.dickimawbooks.bib2gls.SortComparator.sortEntries(SortComparator.java:744)
    at com.dickimawbooks.bib2gls.Bib2GlsEntryComparator.sortEntries(Bib2GlsEntryComparator.java:444)
    at com.dickimawbooks.bib2gls.GlsResource.sortData(GlsResource.java:5203)
    at com.dickimawbooks.bib2gls.GlsResource.sortData(GlsResource.java:5146)
    at com.dickimawbooks.bib2gls.GlsResource.sortDataIfRequired(GlsResource.java:5134)
    at com.dickimawbooks.bib2gls.GlsResource.processBibData(GlsResource.java:5309)
    at com.dickimawbooks.bib2gls.GlsResource.processData(GlsResource.java:4417)
    at com.dickimawbooks.bib2gls.Bib2Gls.process(Bib2Gls.java:1827)
    at com.dickimawbooks.bib2gls.Bib2Gls.main(Bib2Gls.java:4292)
```

the bib file

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@entry{alpha,
 name={\ensuremath{\alpha}},
 description={angular acceleration}
}
@entry{delta,
 name={\ensuremath{\delta}},
 description={Kronecker delta}
}
@entry{lambda,
 name={\ensuremath{\lambda}},
 description={Lagrange multiplier}
}
@entry{chi,
 name={\ensuremath{\chi}},
 description={chromatic number}
}
@entry{zeta,
 name={\ensuremath{\zeta}},
 description={Riemann zeta function}
}
```

The file.tex

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,
   record % using 'bib2gls'
]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={greek-symbols},% entries in 'greek-symbols.bib'
 type=symbols,% put these entries in the 'symbols' glossary
 save-locations=false% don't save locations
]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]

\chapter{Sample}
Reference symbols: $\gls{delta}$, $\gls{chi}$, $\gls{alpha}$,
$\gls{zeta}$, $\gls{lambda}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: A more recent version (1.7) of `bib2gls` runs without error. Try updating your TeX-distribution.

Comment: @DG' I use texlive-2018

Comment: You can install the latest version from [github](https://github.com/nlct/bib2gls) or [ctan](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/bib2gls). The Github page contains detailed installation instructions.

Comment: @alhelal So do I. Try `sudo tlmgr update --all --self`

Comment: @DG' $ sudo tlmgr update --all --self
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/linux/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5336.

Comment: @alhelal You probably used `apt-get` (or something similar) to install TL2018, therefore you could either try to reinstall TL with said package manager or remove it and install it manually again. The following page is very helpful: https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html especially the section on "Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian"

Comment: It could also be the case, that your java installation (or something else) is broken. You could spare yourself the trouble of reinstalling TL by following @Marijn's suggestion and download the most recent version of `bib2gls`...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   java.util.Vector.sort(Ljava/util/Comparator;)V

This indicates that the Java library `java.util.Vector` doesn't have the [`sort(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method. This method was apparently introduced to the `Vector` class in Java 8, so is unavailable for older versions. You therefore need to update your version of Java.